# Any possibilities to dismiss a popover controller when another object is selected?

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I got a MapView on which I edited the callout of my annotations through pushing a UIPopover Controller, on which i added some table views..
I would like to achive that I don't have to click so that my popover controller dismisses when I e.g. select another annotation on the map.. Are there any possibilities to enable these objects in background without clicking?

Any ideas or suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a UIPopoverController is considered modal, the default behaviour is the one you described: you must first close the popover before interacting with the view under it.

You can, however, interact with views under the popover by assigning its `passthroughViews` property:

[UIPopoverController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> When displayed, taps outside of the popover window cause the popover
>   to be dismissed automatically. To allow the user to interact with the
>   specified views and not dismiss the popover, you can assign one or
>   more views to the passthroughViews property.
>
> **passthroughViews**
>
> An array of views that the user can interact with while the popover is
>   visible.
>
> @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *passthroughViews
>
> Discussion
>
> When a popover is active, interactions with other views are
>   normally disabled until the popover is dismissed. Assigning an array
>   of views to this property allows taps outside of the popover to be
>   handled by the corresponding views.

That way, you should be able to interact with your MapView while the popover is showing.

You can dismiss the currently showing popover when you select another annotation by calling `dismissPopoverAnimated:`

> **dismissPopoverAnimated:**
>
> Dismisses the popover programmatically.
>
> - (void)dismissPopoverAnimated:(BOOL)animated
>
> Parameters
>
> animated Specify YES to animate the dismissal of the popover or NO to
>   dismiss it immediately.
>
> Discussion
>
> You can use this method to dismiss the popover programmatically in
>   response to taps inside the popover window. Taps outside of the
>   popover’s contents automatically dismiss the popover.